# Chrome issue when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Am using the confirm message when delete the record from the table.When I click and delete the records got "**prevent this page from creating additional dialogs chrome**".How to disable the prevent this page from creating additional dialogs in Chrome alert?

What are the chrome settings changes are required to disable the messages?I googled lot but no luck.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: You can't disable that.  You just ignore it.  If what you mean is that you want to disable it for your users then you definitely can't.

Comment: @Archer Thanks for your reply.Is possible to hide to show the users?

Comment: @User there's no way.

Comment: If it's the case that you are displaying the dialogs to convey information to the user, maybe you should look at a popup modal window within the page.  Sorta like lightbox

Comment: That option is given to allow the user to turn off your scripts.  If you're concerned about them doing that then I'm concerned about what you're doing!  It's default behaviour and there is no "work round".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, this is a built-in safety net on Chrome (and other browsers, Firefox for example) that you can't work around (nor should you try). Its purpose is to prevent websites "locking" the page by repeatedly throwing alerts; for every alert you dismiss, a new one surfaces. It used to be the case that the whole browsers was "locked" until the alert was dismissed (try it in IE6).

At the risk of going Off Topic, I would be inclined to re-consider your approach: instead of asking the user to confirm an action, give them a means to undo it instead. More often than not, the "delete" action was intentional, so adding the extra interaction is likely to be a PITA for power users. Similarly, it's entirely likely people will become blind to the alerts and dismiss them without even reading them, such that they serve no purpose at all.

See: http://patternry.com/p=undo/ and [Never use a warning when mean Undo](http://alistapart.com/article/neveruseawarning)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It's a behavior of the browser. It doesn't depend on JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Its the default behaviour of Chrome. If you are showing frequent alert/confirm  then it will show this, and the worst thing is if the user check h check box, no alert and confirm will be shown afterwards.

You can use [Jquery Poup](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to show any message or get any data from users